# CKEDITOR does not work and error appears can not read property 'getEditor' at ckeditor.js:321

Tags: javascript

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var data = data.Data;
var html = "";      
for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
     html = html +'<div class="form-group">'+
                       '<label class="control-label col-lg-2">Hasil Rapat</label>'+
                       '<div class="col-lg-10">'+
                           '<textarea rows="20" id="rapat" class="form-control rapat" name="hasil_rpt">'+data[i].hasil_rpt+'</textarea>'+
                       '</div>'+  
                   '</div>'
}
```

I have included the id on the textarea:

```
<textarea rows="20" id="rapat" class="form-control rapat" name="hasil_rpt">'+data[i].hasil_rpt+'</textarea>
```

And I also already use:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('rapat');
```

Comment: What errors appear?

Comment: cannot read property 'getEditor' or undefined

Answer (score 1):

The first red flag I see is that CKEditor isn't going to know how to use your logic. I'm not sure which version of CKEditor you're using as things have drastically changed in v5. But, I think what you need to do is this:

```
var data = data.Data;
var html = "";      
for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++) {
        var id = 'editorId_' + i;
     html = html +'<div class="form-group">'+
                       '<label class="control-label col-lg-2">Hasil Rapat</label>'+
                       '<div class="col-lg-10">'+
                           '<textarea rows="20" id="'+ id + '" class="form-control rapat" name="hasil_rpt">'+data[i].hasil_rpt+'</textarea>'+
                       '</div>'+  
                   '</div>';
    CKEDITOR.replace(id);
}
```

I'm not sure where you are calling `CKEDITOR.replace` from, but it should be either within the `for` loop or in a separate loop after you have completed the loop that adds your html to the DOM. The reason why your code isn't working is because you end up with multiple id's and id's are supposed to be unique. CKEDITOR is tripping over that more than likely.

**EDIT**

The above code isn't going to work since CKEDITOR needs your element reference to be present (and rendered) within the DOM. Once that element is ready, you can then call `CKEDITOR.replace`. A similar flow to this might work:

```
var data = data.Data;
var parentElement = ''; // <-- Get the reference to your container element here
for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++) {
        var id = 'editorId_' + i;
     var html +'<div class="form-group">'+
                       '<label class="control-label col-lg-2">Hasil Rapat</label>'+
                       '<div class="col-lg-10">'+
                           '<textarea rows="20" id="'+ id + '" class="form-control rapat" name="hasil_rpt">'+data[i].hasil_rpt+'</textarea>'+
                       '</div>'+  
                   '</div>';
    parentElement.appendChild(html);
    CKEDITOR.replace(id);
}
```

Comment: And, actually, the above code will not work as your `for` loop is only building the HTML rather than appending it to the DOM. If you appened the html directly into the DOM, you could then successfully call CKEDITOR to instantiate the editor (might be a race condition though).

Comment: If you create a JSFiddle that has your exact issue replaced, I can help you solve it better, but your issue is going to be a matter of making sure the element is actually rendered in the dom before calling CKEDITOR to instaniate it.